# In Java, how would I initialize an array in which elements in an even column or row are 0, and in odd columns or rows, the elements are 1?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I am working on an assignment where I needed to have two 1d arrays, send them to another method, and make a 2d array. I would then have to pass the array back to the main method (all of which I have completed). I now have to print out this 2d array by using for loops in a way that would make all of the elements in even rows or columns 0, and all of the elements in odd rows or columns 1. My code prints all 0s. My code and output is below.

`numRows` and `numColumns` were the arrays that I used to make `oddEven`.

```
for(int j = 0; j < numColumns.length; j++)
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < numRows.length; i++)
        {
            for(int a = 0; a < numColumns.length; a++) //tests for even number column
            {
                if(a % 2 == 0)  
                {
                    oddEven[j][i] = 0;
                }else {
                    oddEven[j][i] = 1;
                }
            }
            for(int b = 0; b < numRows.length; b++) //tests for even number row
            {
                if( b % 2 == 0)
                {
                    oddEven[j][i] = 0;
                }else {
                    oddEven[j][i] = 1;
                }
            }
            System.out.print(oddEven[j][i] + " ");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }   

/*
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0
*/
```

I know how to print out a 2d array, but I have no idea how to do what I just described above.

Here is what the output should be.

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: Your described outcome and example do not match. Do you mean to say that all values where both the row and column indices are even should be one? Also, what is the point of the array if you immediately writing the output?

Answer (score 1):

Write oddEven[j][i] = (i%2)*(j%2)

Comment: I do not understand what that would do. Could you elaborate? Also, I have to use for loop to print it.

Comment: First, only if both i and j are odd, their mod operation both will be 1 which 1*1=1. Otherwise, one of them or both will be 0 which gives you 0 as a result. Second, write two for loops, one traversing over i, the other traversing over j, and put this line at the core of two for loops.

Answer (score 0):

You are unnecessarily iterating through both indices inside the existing loop which is causing every value to be set to zero since you are updating each index with the *last value*.

You only need the two outermost loops. You can simplify your code as such:

```
for(int j = 0; j < numColumns.length; j++)
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < numRows.length; i++)
        {

            oddEven[j][i] = (j%2!=0&&i%2!=0)?1:0;

            System.out.print(oddEven[j][i] + " ");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

To provide further explanation, your `a` loop is pointless as the following `b` loop sets the same values. The value of `oddEven[j][i]` for any `j` and `i` in the range will be set based on `numRows.length - 1` since that will be the last value in your `b` for loop.

**Using an `if` instead of a ternary operator**

```
for(int j = 0; j < numColumns.length; j++)
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < numRows.length; i++)
        {
            if(j%2!=0&&i%2!=0){
                oddEven[j][i]=1;
            }
            else{
                oddEven[j][i]=0;
            }

            System.out.print(oddEven[j][i] + " ");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: The reason I had the ```a``` and ```b``` was to attempt to try and find the even and odd columns, which failed. Also, I just ran your code and it doesn't match the code that it should output, though it was kind of similar.

Comment: You are already iterating through the column indices with `j` and `i`. No need for `a` and `b`. What is wrong with the output?

Comment: Your output is ```10101 (newline) 00000 (newline) 10101 (newline) 00000``` when it should be ```00000 (newline) 01010 (newline) 00000 (newline) 01010``` (sorry for the wierd set up).

Comment: Are the ones and zeroes just inverted then? If so, swap the 1 and 0 in the ternary operator. See my last edit on the answer; the updated code should work as intended.

Comment: My bad, I thought the ones were supposed to be for evens not odds. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I appreciate it very much. But, is there another way to do this? I never learned of the ternary operators you used.(the code worked though)

Comment: Absolutely. A ternary operator is just a short-hand conditional, basically: condition?a:b. If condition is true, it evaluates to a, if false, it evaluates to b. You can easily replace the ternary with an `if` statement it just duplicates code. I'll add more info and a more basic example on the answer since there isn't space in the comment.

Comment: I added an example using an if statement in the answer that is functionally equivalent to the ternary operator. Does that help?

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for helping out. Also, can I have your permission to use and alter the code?

Comment: Of course, otherwise I wouldn't have posted it. Answers on StackOverflow are licensed under the Creative Commons Share Alike license. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing

Comment: Please do accept the answer though if this solved your problem.

Comment: Nice to know! Thanks again, and have a great day! :)